# lib folder is not present inside the '@module-federation/nextjs-mf?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation, nextjs-mf

Hi i am trying to make use of micro front end in nextjs , So as mentioned in this npm pkg link ,

lib folder is not present inside the **@module-federation** package

tried below way to import the include-defaults

```
import '@module-federation/nextjs-mf/lib/include-defaults'
```

but it throws the below error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@module-federation/nextjs-mf/lib/include-defaults'
import App, { AppContext as NextAppContext } from 'next/app'
import '@module-federation/nextjs-mf/lib/include-defaults'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find files inside the src folder, So we can point src like below

```
import '@module-federation/nextjs-mf/src/include-defaults'
```

This will importing lib as expected ,

** Note but i am not sure , why the lib folder and its files are not there in the package